# Mongoose model select query with empty fields present

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I write:

```
User.find({}).select('email firstName lastName').exec(...)
```

I'd expect the resulting `user` to have the following structure:

```
{
  email: 'user@email.com',
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null
}
```

even if `firstName` and `lastName` aren't set for this record. Instead I get:

```
{
  email: 'user@email.com'
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: add them by yourself

Comment: This can't be guessed automatically by the model definition or something?

Comment: You can achieve it using `aggregation`

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comment, you can achieve that result with help of aggregation and [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/#exp._S_ifNull) operator. In mongoose it will look like:

```
User.aggregate(
    [
        {$project: {
            _id:0,
            email: {$ifNull: ["$email", null]},
            firstName: {$ifNull: ["$firstName", null]},
            lastName: {$ifNull: ["$lastName", null]}
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {
        // Result is an array of documents
    }
)
```

Comment: Is this the *mongoose way* to do this? I'm always confused between querying with the mongodb *raw* syntax or using the mongoose formalism.